# Minimum sum combination on selecting one element for each index out of 3 arrays

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, combinations

Given 3 non-sorted indexed sequence of real numbers. Out of the combinations obtained by selecting exactly one element out of 3 elements (one from each array) with same index, which combination yields sum with minimum absolute value? All elements are real numbers and can be negative.

```
First array : a1, a2, a3, ..., an
Second array : b1, b2, b3, ..., bn
Third array : c1, c2, c3, ..., cn

One combination on selecting one element from each index is
a1, b2, c3, a4, b5, c6, ... ,cn

The sum of this combination is a1 + b2 + c3 + ... + cn.
I am trying to find the combination with minimum absolute value of sum.
```

There are `3^n` such combinations and hence iterating through all of them is not possible for high value of n (~10 million). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think you can do better than exponential?

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid looking at all $3^n$ possibilities. One of them just might have zero sum.

Comment: 3 is more than a million digits numbers for n = 1e7. How can I look at all such possibilities?

Comment: Where is the problem from?